# Im being asked to to initialize a list, l_counts with as many 0 as characters in the English alphabet

Tags: python-3.x

L_counts will keep the count for 'a' at position 0, the count for 'b'  at position 1, and so on. i must have a way to know what English letter corresponds to each position in L_counts. im not quite understanding the instruction so if i create a empty list or in the list put 0 - 2.

```
L_count = []

L_counts = [0,1,2,3.. so on]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any problem with the following?

```
L_Count = [0]*26
```